# Visual C++, multiple for loops using same iterator name, visible outside of scope in debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 and have multiple for loops where I use the same name for the iterator, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // do something
}
....
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // do something else
}
```

When I step through in debug mode, after leaving the first for loop the first 'i' remains visible in the Locals window at its final value 10, even though it has gone out of scope. Then I enter the second for loop and I now have two i's showing (albeit with different values). It's a slight annoyance because I'll break somewhere on another condition and I can't immediately see what the value of i is. I can get around that by just declaring 'i' once outside the iterator scope:

```
int i;
...
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // do something
}
...
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // do something else
}
```

But it still bothers me because it seems inconsistent. I would expect to see the same behavior as this, where the first 'i' disappears from the Locals window once it goes out of scope:

```
{
  int i = 0;}
}
...
{
  int i = 1;
}
```

I want to know whether it's just a Microsoft thing, or if I don't properly understand scoping in for loops ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice catch.

To me, it sounds like a compiler bug more or less. There is an option in VC to select to "*Force Conformance In For Loop Scope*" so that the for loop variable goes out of scope outside for loop.

However, that doesn't fix the issue you mentioned in the debugger. Regardless of which option you select, both variables are there in the debugger, which appears to be confusing.

The only way to distinguish between them is that out-of-scope `i` should have value `0xcccccccc` in debug mode. This should be compiler specific, and WinDbg handles it in a different way, as mentioned in the following article.

What I tried: VC2008, VC2012

There is a [good article](http://www.echobit.com/blog/bit/2008/10/for-loops-and-the-visual-studio-debugger/) well experimenting this issue.

Comment: Thanks, that is a useful reference and explains in more detail what I was observing.

Comment: @EricZ, I think it is a bug in the debugger. The compiler seems to behave as per MS documentation.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC has a special compiler flag that can affect the scoping of `int i` in your examples: [/Zc:forScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84wcsx8x.aspx).

It's on by default, but the debugger is probably set up to accommodate for it to be turned off with /Zc:forScope- which *would* make the following code valid (even though it's not standards-compliant):

```
{
    for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    for(i=0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you've accidentally turned it off, your code is *not* working as you (and the C++ standard) expect, but then you'd probably get a warning on redeclaring `i`.

Comment: Yes. It behaves exactly as described in the question whether or not /Zc:forScope is enabled or disabled. My code compiles and runs iff the flag is disabled, in which case the single instance of `i` stays in the locals pane.

Comment: Which MSVC version are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry, what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: I observe different behaviours on 2008 and 2012.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Visual Studio that controls whether the scope of variables defined in a `for` loop are visible beyond the `for` loop. It's called `/Zc:forScope`. When you use `/Zc:forScope-`, you get the behavior you described. To change the behavior to conform to C++ stanards, you have to use `/Zc:forScope`

More information can be found at [MSDN Website: /Zc:forScope (Force Conformance in for Loop Scope)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84wcsx8x.aspx).

Comment: @EricZ Yes, I have, with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this feature thanks, but I checked and I did actually have /Zc:forScope on as per default. No question 'i' is actually going out of scope as it should between the two loops (e.g. I get an undeclared identifier error if I insert a line with "i = 0;" between the two loops). What still mystifies me is the fact that the first 'i' remains visible during debugging in the Locals window after it has gone out of scope. Were you able to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: @R, you sure? I tried 2008, 2012. Both of them have the issue that OP mentioned. Choosing either option doesn't help.

Comment: @EricZ, the problem with the debugger, as described by the OP, is there. regardless of whether I use `/Zc:forScope` or `/Zc:forScope-`.

Comment: @R: Yeap, I saw that too on 2012. That could be a bug, or at least something to improve.